# phpstan error installing Upgrade Status module

Tags: composer

I'm on a freshly updates site running PHP 8.1.12. I followed the instructions on the module page. Worked fine till the final step when it failed.

```
  Problem 1
    - mglaman/phpstan-drupal[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.16] require phpstan/phpstan ^1.0 -> found phpstan/phpstan[1.0.0, ..., 1.9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - mglaman/phpstan-drupal[1.1.17, ..., 1.1.20] require phpstan/phpstan ^1.7.0 -> found phpstan/phpstan[1.7.0, ..., 1.9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - mglaman/phpstan-drupal[1.0.x-dev, ..., 1.1.25] require phpstan/phpstan ^1.6.0 -> found phpstan/phpstan[1.6.0, ..., 1.9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - drupal/upgrade_status[3.18.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require mglaman/phpstan-drupal ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mglaman/phpstan-drupal[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.25].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/upgrade_status ^3.18 -> satisfiable by drupal/upgrade_status[3.18.0, 3.x-dev].
```

I used these commands right off the module's page instructions:

```
composer show drupal/core | grep versions
composer require --dev drupal/core-dev:9.4.8 --update-with-all-dependencies
composer require drupal/upgrade_status --update-with-all-dependencies
```

There is nothing in my composer.json about upgrade_status or phpstan.Here is the complete file:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "0": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/mcaskill/composer-merge-plugin"
        },
        "1": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "2": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        "3": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.2",
        "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.6",
        "drupal/anti_duplicates": "^3.1",
        "drupal/antibot": "^1.4",
        "drupal/blazy": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/block_class": "^1.1",
        "drupal/block_visibility_groups": "^1.3",
        "drupal/captcha": "^1.6",
        "drupal/composer_deploy": "^1.6",
        "drupal/computed_field": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/config_update": "^1.6",
        "drupal/contact_block": "^1.4.0",
        "drupal/core": "^9",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
        "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^9",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.2.0",
        "drupal/embed": "^1.3",
        "drupal/encrypt": "^3.0",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.2.0",
        "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.7",
        "drupal/features": "^3.8.0",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.3",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.2",
        "drupal/fivestar": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/flag": "^4.0",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
        "drupal/image_url_formatter": "^1.0",
        "drupal/imce": "^2.2",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0.0-rc2",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.11",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.10.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.6.0",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/real_aes": "^2.3",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.5",
        "drupal/schema_metatag": "^2.1",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.6",
        "drupal/simplenews": "^2.0",
        "drupal/slick": "^2.0",
        "drupal/slick_extras": "^1.0.0-rc2",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^2.3",
        "drupal/social_media_links": "^2.6.0",
        "drupal/token": "^1.5.0",
        "drupal/tvi": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/twig_field_value": "^2.0",
        "drupal/views_bulk_edit": "^2.7",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^3.9",
        "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.6.0",
        "drupal/votingapi": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.0",
        "drush/drush": "^10.0.0",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-feature/composer-v2 as 1.5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "9.4.8",
        "kint-php/kint": "^4.2",
        "palantirnet/drupal-rector": "^0.11.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": true,
            "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-types": [
            "npm-asset",
            "bower-asset"
        ],
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:npm-asset",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:drupal-library",
                "bower-asset/bLazy",
                "bower-asset/jquery.easing",
                "npm-asset/slick-carousel"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, youâ€™ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        },
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Add to the question exactly what you typed and add to the question an example composer.json file that exhibits the issue.

Comment: I just edited my question. I haven't installed this before so there isn't anything in the composer.json file.

Comment: So composer.json is an empty file?

Comment: I added it above

Answer (score 1):

The drupal-rector constraint is incompatible with the current version of upgrade_status. Try the following:

```sh
composer require --dev palantirnet/drupal-rector --with-all-dependencies
composer require drupal/upgrade_status --update-with-all-dependencies
```

Comment: That did the trick thanks. It installed but gives me an error at the top I'll have to figure out:
"The PHP binary was not found. Scanning is not possible until this is resolved" Not very helpful, but I'll track it down. Thanks again.

Comment: I experienced the same problem minus the php binary part.
Upgrading drupal/upgrade_rector, not palantirnet/drupal-rector,  did the trick for me.